# Referencing values or methods in inner case-class directly

Tags: scala, composition, case-class

I'd like to make the API of a composed case class a little cleaner. So, consider a modified version of the classic example:

```
case class Address(street: String, city: String, zip: String) {
    some large collection of methods
}
case class Person(name: String, address: Address) {
    val street = address.street
    val city = address.city
    val zip = address.zip
}
```

Now, I like this because you can get the address info directly from the person like `person.city` instead of requiring `person.address.city`

However if we imagine that there are a large number of values or methods on the `Address` case class and it would be tedious to `val x = address.x` in the Person class. Is there some way to directly access field, values, and methods in address from a person without mapping them all by hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one option is to use an implicit conversion. but i would not justify how clean this approach is:

```
case class Address(street: String)
case class Person(name: String, address: Address) {
  private val s = this.street
}
implicit def person2address(p: Person): Address = p.address

Person("alex", Address("street")).street
```

also [self types](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/self-types.html) could be used:

```
case class Person(name: String, address: Address) {
  _: Address =>
  private val s = street
}
```

Comment: Implicit conversion seems to do what I asked. I wouldn't have thought to use it that way. Thanks.